# how to make a text boxes text move back and forth?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, timer, textbox

hello atm I have this code

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            x = 0;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (x <= 10)
        {
            x++;
            string ping = new string(' ', x) + "hello";
            label1.Text = ping;
            if (x == 10)
            {
                y = 10;
            }
        }
        else if (y > 0)
        {
            y--;
            string pong = new string(' ', y) + "hello";
            label1.Text = pong;
            if (y == 0)
            {
                x = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

at the moment the label has a maximum length of 15 characters and i want it to stay that way.

but i want it to instead of using "hello" to take the text i input into a textbox and do it.

however it has to take 15 and subtract the length of the textboxes text in order to keep the labels max length of 15 intact while displaying the entire word in the textbox aswell but i cant figure out how to do it i have tried plenty of things but i cannot figure it out any help would be greatly appreciated. :D

Comment: You can tie the code from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/MarqueeLabelHost.htm) to your timer incrementing its position on each tick.

Comment: Not quite sure of exactly what your after. What you seem to be doing is moving the word hello to the right then to the left by padding out with spaces. Your could move the label control by changing the Left (x) and Top (y) properties. The same could be done with text box control. I assume your just experimenting with animation here and not designing a user interface. Might be a little too much 'fun' for a user to have to hit a moving text box with their mouse.

Comment: basically i am trying to replace the hello with the text of a textbox but the labels maximum length is 15 so i dont know how to incorporate that

i would do 15 - textbox1.text.length right? but it wont let me make a private int for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of the words "ping" and "pong", plus your title saying "move back and forth" leads me to believe the result you want can be achieved by changing the TextAlign property of the label upon each tick.

If this is the result you want, you won't have to add spaces at all.  The text will appear to go from left to right edges in the label.  You might consider trimming the text property with TRIM() to ensure no spaces exist on either side that would make it appear aligned incorrectly.

Comment: how would i do this?
im not very familiar with a lot of things in c#

Comment: also it is aligned correctly
i just want to be able to use a textbox in place of "hello"

Comment: but also keep the labels max character length at 15

Comment: Upon each timer's tick, do this: If (Label1.TextAlign == MiddleLeft) {Label1.TextAlign = MiddleRight;} else {Label1.TextAlign == MiddleLeft;}  (Bear in mind, I'm a VB.NET guy but I believe this is approximately correct for C#.  In comments I can't show proper linebreaks of course.)

Comment: Oops I had a == where I should have had just = but you probably spotted that.  (That's how VB guys are used to doing things.)  Of course, you'll also want to set the text property to whatever you want which can be from a textbox.  Did you want it to "gradually" move from side to side, one space at a time, or did you want it to move instantly upon each tick?

Comment: In place of "Hello" use Trim(Mid(TextBox1.Text, 1, 15)).  This will ensure that if the textbox has more than 15 characters in it, only 15 will be used.  Of course, if your Label uses a monospaced font (like a typewriter or Notepad) and you have EXACTLY 15 characters, it may not appear to move at all depending on the width of the label.

Comment: how about this can you just tell me how i would declare the variable
int i = textBox1.Text.Length so it can be used globaly? I tried to do
private int i = textBox1.Text.Length but it doesnt work and I get an error

Comment: By "globally" do you mean anywhere within the form?  The feeling I'm getting is this is a 1-form application, so I'm assuming so.  Try "Public Int i = 15" in the declaration of your form...or you can use zero instead of 15 but you should not use textbox1.text.length.  Remember the textbox doesn't "exist" until the form is loaded so you can't set it to the length of the textbox's text property in its declarations.  Then, in the form's load event you can use i = textbox1.length if you wish.